# In a Rails controller creating a new index in a 'map.do' loop fails, yet it's fine in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of records from a database using `select id, parent_id....` and loop over them using `map.do` creating a new index on each row.

```
records = results.map do |row|
    row['childs'] = {}
    comments[row['id']] = row
end
```

This works fine when called from the command-line but when placed in the Rails context I get the following error:

```
>ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in CommentsController#index
can't write unknown attribute `childs'
```

Any idea what this would work in Ruby at the command line and not Rails? What am I missing about how Rails works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row` is not a hash, but an `ActiveModel` object instance, so you can't just add/assign new attributes to it like a key to the hash. In your model, you can use `attr_accessor` to initiate setters(writing) and getters(reading) for `childs` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately adding the attr_accessor didn't work.

Comment: @user3096851: post what the whole method then, and tell, what `results` and `comments` contain

Comment: Sorry my last comment was so brief.  Here's the code in one full script.

Comment: results = client.query("SELECT id, parent_id, title, votes, popularity FROM >comments WHERE thread_id = 1 order by popularity desc, posted asc")
    comments = {}
    records = results.map do |row|row['childs'] = {}
  comments[row['id']] = row
end
comments.map do |k, v|
 if v["parent_id"] != 0
  #puts v["parent_id"]
  comments[v["parent_id"]]['childs'][k] =  v
 end
end
comments.map do |k, v|
 if v["parent_id"] != 0
  comments.delete(k)
 end
end

Comment: def display_comments(comments, level = 0)
 comments.map do |k,v|
  puts '-' * (level + 1) + " " + comments[k]["title"] + " (id: " + comments[k]["id"].to_s + ")\n"
  display_comments(comments[k]['childs], level + 1)
 end
end
display_comments(comments)